# How to smooth my Topology

Tags: edges

I managed to cut a hole in my mesh without adding extra verts but now I have a problem with the smoothing. It doesn't smooth the edges around the whole as you can see. How can i fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to change the direction of the edge flow so there is a loop around the "hole". You can do this by selecting the corner vertices (in pairs) and merging them at the center.

[image: Merge]

You can then add an edge loop around the hole and pull it in to define the top of the edge.

[image: EdgeLoop]

If you want the inside of the hole to look "cleaner", add an edge loop in the center, and bevel it until the top and bottom edges are close to their counterparts in the hole. You might also want to select the bottom faces and inset them very slightly.

[image: BevelLoop]

Final result is a clean cutout:

[image: CutoutFinal]

Comment: thanks bro, what do you mean by inset?

Comment: Select all the bottom faces and press "i". You can then move the mouse to see what it does - it brings a new loop in from the edge. You can also put a numerical value. I used `I > .01` to get a small inset.